# Billing system best practices

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, oop, billing

I'm currently developing a web application for one of my clients. This client requested a  small billing module. The client istelf is small SIP provider. There are several pricing items, plans, etc. All they different types of payment like onetime, monthly, annual. Are there any best practices, good books, articles on blling systems architecure?

Btw the web app based on symfony framework.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is usually nothing "small" about a billing system.

I just ran across something called [citrusdb](http://www.citrusdb.org).  You might want to go through it to decide if you want to build something or just integrate theirs.

Barring that, depending on their business they might be better served just using QuickBooks in combination with an online ordering / payment system.

Comment: Wow! Great. I'll look into it. Will be good if i can import customers into this system.

Comment: +1. Always be wary when a client asks for a "small" feature, its often actually bigger than the rest of system.

Comment: @devstuff: I completely agree.  My experience has been if the customer uses the word "small" then they have looked into it and the off the shelf solution was more than they wanted to pay and are hoping a programmer can write it for less.

Comment: Nice result i got. I asked my client about QuickBooks! They already got it. So i'll need only integrate it with our app :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that this may actually turn into a relatively "small" feature after all. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some Google Books? Some are available with extended previews, that can be helpful.
http://books.google.com/books?id=lOImNtO96L0C

Flow Charts?
http://www.google.com/images?q=billing+process+flow+chart

You can also get some useful info from audit programs, that describe the kind of things you (or your system, probably) will be asked to produce. Ctrl-F Billing:
http://www.dcaa.mil/standardguidance.htm

These are very general, and not very specific to any programming language. Hope it helps :)